# Subsetting 700+ fips codes

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a a list of 700+ fips codes that I'm trying to subset into a smaller dataset.  I know I could just list them all out like this :

```
data <- data[(data$fips == 65409, 84840, etc....) ,]
```

But this is unrealistic as I have 700+ fips codes to subset.  I'm looking for a way to subset using a list of fips codes I get from :

```
fips <- unique(DustBowlData_Pre$fips)   #Get all fips codes
```

Edit : I tried to clarify further, but it's hard to submit an example because of the sheer number.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Please add expected output. It is not clear what you trying to do.

Comment: "it's hard to submit an example because of the sheer number": Please read [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked.

```
prism.dd <- prism.d[(prism.d$fips %in% fips) ,]
```